# Calendar not working and freezing

Tags: iphone, ical

My calendar has made copies of all the birthdays of my Facebook friends and has created individual calendar for each of those.

I cannot use the Calendar app at all. It takes about 10-15 seconds to load when I click on it. I have tried everything that has been posted on the forums and nothing works.

I currently have about 500 individual calendars in the app and my battery life on my brand new iPhone 7 iOS 10.2 is about 4 hours max, providing that is in 'Low Battery Mode'. Help please

Comment: Could you provide us with the things you already tried out?

Comment: turned off calendar sharing on FB, disabled all other accounts sharing calendar. The only 2 accounts which calendar is enabled on is iCloud and one of my email accounts.

Comment: turned off calendar sharing on FB, disabled all other accounts sharing calendar. The only 2 accounts which calendar is enabled on is iCloud and one of my email accounts.I have currently around 300 individual calendars created in the app that are from my FB friends but that was turned off. What do you think I should do next?

Comment: Can you delete all those calendars?

Comment: And turn off the visibility.